# Why does Hegel suggest that rationality may go against itself eventually?

Tags: hegel

Hegel's view on Kant's antinomy is that it uncovers the inherent contradiction of rationality. I don't get it that the concept negates itself through logical deduction. My example is sponetanity vs causation. Causation consists of cause and result, However, when you attempt to find out the ultimate source of cause, it turns out to be that there must be a sponetaneous cause,which is a contradiction to causation.

Comment: This kind of question calls for at least one extended quote. Preferably a couple. Otherwise, people are likely to be talking past each other.

Comment: In the top answer to your [previous question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/97938/9148) it was already explained that Hegel does not use formal logic and does not talk about logical negation or logical contradictions, so there is no "negates itself through logical deduction". Self-causing does not logically contradict causation, there is nothing in the concept of cause that logically precludes a thing from being its own cause. "Contradiction of rationality" in Kant's antinomies is not a logical contradiction  either, as Kant himself explained, to Hegel it reflects dynamics of reason.

Comment: @Conifold Apology for my oblivion, I still don't figure out why dynamics of reason draws conclusion contradictory to precondition as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: "Contradictory" does not mean in Hegel what it usually means. In developing its concepts reason delimits ("determines") them, i.e. identifies both properties they have and those they don't. This is Hegel's "determinate negation". With those negative properties it posits the opposite of the concept, the "contradictory", that which it is not, but positively described. Thereby delimited within their respective domains, both the original and its opposite find their proper place in a broader ("sublated") concept. And then it starts over. This is Hegel's dialectical movement of thought.